# Libgdx | Loading TTF fonts with AssetManager holds up main thread

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I use the bitmapfont loader and truetypefontparam to load fonts with AssetManager while splash screen fades in/out. Fading the splash screen lags when loading the fonts. The main thread is being held up when loading the fonts in AssetManager. I confirmed this by printing something in console in the update method of my splash screen. When not loading the fonts, this problem is fixed. I will show my code, I am doing something wrong? I sorry for my bad English.

```
public void loadFonts() {

    FreeTypeFontGenerator.setMaxTextureSize(FreeTypeFontGenerator.NO_MAXIMUM);
    FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
    Game.assetManager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
    Game.assetManager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".ttf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));

    FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter parameter = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    parameter.fontParameters.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest;
    parameter.fontParameters.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;

    parameter.fontFileName = "fonts/score.ttf";
    parameter.fontParameters.size = 200;
    parameter.fontParameters.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Game.assetManager.load("score.ttf", BitmapFont.class, parameter);

    parameter = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    parameter.fontFileName = "fonts/score.ttf";
    parameter.fontParameters.size = 100;
    parameter.fontParameters.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Game.assetManager.load("touchToStart.ttf", BitmapFont.class, parameter);

    parameter = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    parameter.fontFileName = "fonts/octo.ttf";
    parameter.fontParameters.size = 100;
    parameter.fontParameters.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Game.assetManager.load("highScore.ttf", BitmapFont.class, parameter);

    parameter = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    parameter.fontFileName = "fonts/octo.ttf";
    parameter.fontParameters.size = 222;
    parameter.fontParameters.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Game.assetManager.load("popupMenu.ttf", BitmapFont.class, parameter);

    parameter = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    parameter.fontFileName = "fonts/octo.ttf";
    parameter.fontParameters.size = 200;
    parameter.fontParameters.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Game.assetManager.load("gameOver.ttf", BitmapFont.class, parameter);

}
```

--

```
private void loadAssets() {

    FontManager.getFontManager().loadFonts(); //Load fonts is the method above

    Game.assetManager.load("assets.txt", TextureAtlas.class);
    Game.assetManager.load("assets2.txt", TextureAtlas.class);

    Game.assetManager.load("sound/tap.mp3", Sound.class);
    Game.assetManager.load("sound/point.mp3", Sound.class);
    Game.assetManager.load("sound/death.mp3", Sound.class);

}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong. Generating a font is slow, and is not supported asynchronously. Generating the glyphs could probably be done on a background thread if someone is willing to update Libgdx.

Comment: @Tenfour04 It takes 4 seconds just to load these fonts. Isn't that alot?

Comment: Not at all. It has to load the font file to memory, read the dimensions of all the glyphs, figure out how to arrange them all onto the smallest size image possible, draw every one of those glyphs to a Pixmap, and then load the Pixmap to the GPU as a Texture.  Typically, if you use FreetypeFontGenerator, you only do it the first time your app opens. Then you save the fonts and load them directly from then on.